# Cannot get desired interface using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been working on a small project in which a calculator must be embedded in a box. I am using **Tkinter**.

My code:

```
import tkinter

top = tkinter.Tk()

def add(x, y):
  return x + y

def subtract(x, y):
  return x - y

def multiply(x, y):
  return x * y

def divide(x, y):
  return x / y

print("Select operation.")
print("1.Add")
print("2.Subtract")
print("3.Multiply")
print("4.Divide")

choice = input("Enter choice(1/2/3/4):")
num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))

if choice == '1':
  print(num1,"+",num2,"=", add(num1,num2))
elif choice == '2':
  print(num1,"-",num2,"=", subtract(num1,num2))
elif choice == '3':
  print(num1,"*",num2,"=", multiply(num1,num2))
elif choice == '4':
  print(num1,"/",num2,"=", divide(num1,num2))
else:
  print("Invalid input")

top.mainloop()
```

The problem is that the  calculator is not opening inside the box. I am getting the following output:

```
Select operation.
1.Add
2.Subtract
3.Multiply
4.Divide
Enter choice(1/2/3/4): 3
Enter first number: 15
Enter second number: 14
15 * 14 = 210
```

What I need is to display it inside the box.

Comment: `print` does not magically print to a tkinter window. You'll have to actually create some widgets for input/output.

Comment: i didnt get you ..widgets ??..can you explain more ..or give me some examples ..it would be great

Comment: you mean..i want to create a inputt box and retrieve data from input box ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not created a "box", so displaying things inside one is going to be difficult until you do.

The line:

```
top = tkinter.Tk()
```

creates the root window for a `Tkinter` GUI. To print things inside of it, you need to add a widget (a GUI element) that you can write to in the root window. A good option here is a `Text` widget:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
my_text = tk.Text(root)
my_text.pack()
```

Now to print to the text box instead of the terminal, you can replace your print statements by the `Text.insert` method.

```
my_text.insert(tk.END,"Hello, this is some text\n")
my_text.insert(tk.END,"This is some other text\n")
my_text.insert("0.0","This is some text starting at row 0 and column 0\n")
my_text.insert(tk.CURRENT,"This is even more text, this time starting from the current cursor position\n")
```

Comment: can i write like  my_text.insert(tk.END,(num1,"-",num2,"=", subtract(num1,num2)) ?

Comment: You will have to turn that into a string first, so: `my_text.insert(tk.END,"".join((num1,"-",num2,"=", subtract(num1,num2)))` or `my_text.insert(tk.END,"%d-%d=%d"%(num1,num2,subtract(num1,num2)))` will work.

Comment: but when i add choice = my_text.insert(tk.END,input("Enter choice(1/2/3/4):")) ..it doesnt work bro

Comment: Long comment threads on SO are frowned upon. New questions should be posted as using the "Ask Question" button rather than in the comments.

Comment: do you know the answer why am getting like this ..if yes please share